# Calling rsync with pexpect: glob string not working

Tags: python-2.7, shell, glob, pexpect

I'm attempting to `rsync` some files with `pexpect`.  It appears the glob string argument I'm providing to identify all the source files is not working.

The gist of it is something like this...

```
import pexpect
import sys

glob_str = (
    "[0-9]" * 4 + "-" +
    "[0-9]" * 2 + "-" +
    "[0-9]" * 2 + "-" +
    "[A-B]" + "*"
)

SRC = "../data/{}".format(glob_str)
DES = "user@host:" + "/path/to/dest/"

args = [
    "-avP",
    SRC,
    DES,
]

print "rsync" + " ".join(args)

# Execute the transfer
child = pexpect.spawn("rsync", args)
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout  # log what the child sends back
child.expect("Password:")
child.sendline("#######")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Fails with this...

```
building file list ...
rsync: link_stat "/Users/U6020643/git/ue-sme-query-logs/code/../data/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[A-B]*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider
...
```

The same command run in the shell works just fine

```
rsync -avP ../data/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[A-B].csv username@host:/path/to/dest/
```

The [pexpect documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html) mentions this

> Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as redirect, pipe, or wild cards (>, |, or *). This is a common mistake. If you want to run a command and pipe it through another command then you must also start a shell.

But doing so...

```
...
args = [
    "rsync",
    "-avP",
    SRC,
    DES,
]
...
child = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash", args)  # have to use a shell for glob expansion to work
...
```

Runs into a permissions issue

```
/usr/bin/rsync: /usr/bin/rsync: cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `rsync` with `bash` you have to use `bash -c "cmd..."`:

```
args = ["-c", "rsync -avP {} {}".format(SRC, DES)]
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', args=args)
```

And I think you can also try `rsync --include=PATTERN`.

Comment: Is there a way not to use a shell? It might be dangerous especially when your input comes from the user.

Comment: if u dont use shell syntax then u dont have to use a shell.